# Indentation trouble when communicating between modules with shinymeta

Tags: r, shiny

I have several modules and the goal of one of them is to collect all the `meta` expressions and to put them into a single `verbatimTextOutput`. After having read [this article on communication between modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicate-bet-modules.html), I tried to adapt it with `shinymeta` expressions but I am having some trouble doing so.

Here's an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymeta)

small_mod_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  selectInput(ns("test"), "test", choices = names(mtcars))
}
small_mod_server <- function(input, output, session){
  return(
    list(
      test_reactive = metaReactive({
        ..(input$test)
      }), 
      test_reactive_2 = metaReactive({
        ..(input$test)
      })
    )
  )
}

code_mod_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  verbatimTextOutput(ns("show_code"))
}
code_mod_server <- function(input, output, session, com_between_mods){
  output$show_code <- renderPrint({
    expandChain(
      com_between_mods$test_reactive(),
      com_between_mods$test_reactive_2()
    )
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  small_mod_ui("1"),
  code_mod_ui("1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  com_between_mods <- callModule(small_mod_server, "1")
  callModule(code_mod_server, "1", com_between_mods = com_between_mods)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Running this example throws this error:

> Warning: Error in : :2:2: unexpected input
>   1: `1_test_reactive` <- "mpg"
>   2: 1_
>       ^
>     134:

However, replacing

```
return(
  list(
      test_reactive = metaReactive({
        ..(input$test)
      }), 
      test_reactive_2 = metaReactive({
        ..(input$test)
      })
    )
  )
```

by

```
  return(list(test_reactive = metaReactive({ ..(input$test) }), test_reactive_2 = metaReactive({ ..(input$test) }) ))
```

(on a single line) seems to fix the problem.

Is there an "indentation condition" in `shinymeta`?

Also asked [on RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/indentation-trouble-when-communicating-between-modules-with-shinymeta/64727)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by Joe Cheng [on GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/shinymeta/issues/84#issuecomment-632391613)